# HTML table thead not aligning with tbody

Tags: jquery, html

I think I am doing something wrong, but my table cells are not aligned. The `<thead>` cells are not aligning with the `<tbody>` (and `<tfoot>`) cells. This happens in Chrome and Firefox (**note**: I'm on Linux so I don't/can't test IE.).

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuHzm/).

[image]

```
$(container)
    .append($("<table>")
         .append($("<thaad>").html("<tr><th>ID</th><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Email</th><th>Active</th></tr>"))
         .append($("<tfoot>").html("<tr><th>ID</th><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Email</th><th>Active</th></tr>"))
         .append($("<tbody>").html("<tr><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>john@email.com</td><td>true</td></tr>")));
```

What could be the reason for this? How to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote `thaad` insead of `thead`. :)

Comment: D'oh! I've been at it for way too long. Thanks.

Comment: Haha no problem. Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes.